# JW Player construction/build not playing ads

Tags: javascript, jwplayer, vast, jwplayer7

I am trying to build JWPlayer using instructions in GitHub
https://github.com/jwplayer/jwplayer

After building the player, the pretag ad is not working, is it related to license or something like that ?

I mean , there is no instruction to set any license or key while building, does that build support advertisements ?

Answer (score 0):

the open-source player found on the repo does not contain any features that are only available to Premium accounts or higher. This means that if you are trying to play a HLS stream with the open-source player, you can expect to see a “No Playable Sources Found” error since HLS playback is not supported in the Free version of the player.

Comment: If I have premium account, how do I customize the player and build it myslef ?